# Categorization of electromagnetic solitons?

Tags: electromagnetism, non-linear-optics, non-linear-systems, solitons

I've seen over the years several mentions of electromagnetic solitons that appear in the high-intensity regime (where vacuum polarization becomes important). Some of these are coupled with plasmas, others in vacuum. Almost all I've known about, propagate with time-like group velocities. There is [one that beats the diffraction limit of gaussian beams](http://www.mit.edu/~soljacic/QED.pdf). I'm sure there are others with interesting properties as well.

What I haven't seen is any attempt to classify and categorize all these phenomena in some kind of taxonomy. Is any one aware of attempts toward this in the literature?

Comment: In plasma physics, there are several types of solitons (e.g., Langmuir and magnetosonic).  The magnetosonic solitons have a few forms, but the one that has definitely been observed was originally called short large amplitude magnetic structures or SLAMS.  In most cases that I have encountered, solitons come in two large groups: (1) solutions to KdV-like equations; and (2) solutions to nonlinear Schrödinger equations.